# Convert to a Partitioned Table

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have the following table structure with live data in it:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userstatistics` (
   `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `number_logons` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_profileminiviews` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_profilefullviews` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_mailsreceived` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_interestreceived` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_favouratesreceived` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_friendshiprequestreceived` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_imchatrequestreceived` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `yearweek` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`yearweek`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to convert this to a partitioned table with the following structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userstatistics` (
   `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `number_logons` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_profileminiviews` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_profilefullviews` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_mailsreceived` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_interestreceived` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_favouratesreceived` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_friendshiprequestreceived` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `number_imchatrequestreceived` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `yearweek` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`yearweek`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
 /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (yearweek)
 (PARTITION userstats_201108 VALUES LESS THAN (201108) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201109 VALUES LESS THAN (201109) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201110 VALUES LESS THAN (201110) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201111 VALUES LESS THAN (201111) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201112 VALUES LESS THAN (201112) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201113 VALUES LESS THAN (201113) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201114 VALUES LESS THAN (201114) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201115 VALUES LESS THAN (201115) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201116 VALUES LESS THAN (201116) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201117 VALUES LESS THAN (201117) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201118 VALUES LESS THAN (201118) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201119 VALUES LESS THAN (201119) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201120 VALUES LESS THAN (201120) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_201121 VALUES LESS THAN (201121) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION userstats_max VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;
```

How can I do this conversion?

Simply changing the first line of the second SQL statement to

```
 ALTER TABLE 'userstatistics' (
```

Would this do it?

Going from MySQL 5.0 to 5.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to be running MySQL 5.1 or later.  MySQL 5.0 does not support partitioning.

Second, please be aware of the difference between single-quotes (which delimit strings and dates) and back-ticks (which delimit table and column identifiers in MySQL).  Use the correct type where appropriate.  I mention this, because your example uses the wrong type of quotes:

```
ALTER TABLE 'userstatistics' (
```

That should be:

```
ALTER TABLE `userstatistics` (
```

Finally, yes, you can restructure a table into partitions with ALTER TABLE.  Here's an exact copy & paste from a statement I tested on MySQL 5.1.57:

```
ALTER TABLE userstatistics PARTITION BY RANGE (yearweek)  (
PARTITION userstats_201108 VALUES LESS THAN (201108) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201109 VALUES LESS THAN (201109) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201110 VALUES LESS THAN (201110) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201111 VALUES LESS THAN (201111) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201112 VALUES LESS THAN (201112) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201113 VALUES LESS THAN (201113) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201114 VALUES LESS THAN (201114) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201115 VALUES LESS THAN (201115) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201116 VALUES LESS THAN (201116) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201117 VALUES LESS THAN (201117) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201118 VALUES LESS THAN (201118) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201119 VALUES LESS THAN (201119) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201120 VALUES LESS THAN (201120) ENGINE = InnoDB,   
PARTITION userstats_201121 VALUES LESS THAN (201121) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
PARTITION userstats_max VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB);
```

Note that this causes a *table restructure*, so if you already have a lot of data in this table, it will take a while to run.  Exactly how long depends on how much data you have, and your hardware speed, and other factors.  Be aware that while the table is being restructured, it is locked and unavailable for reading and writing by other queries.

Comment: Bill's step by step documentation is certainly better than help menu. :-) And this partition assumes you will do more range query in a single month.

Comment: [Percona Toolkit's `pt-online-schema-change`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65506/152463) claims to be able to partition online MySQL tables **_without_ the _table restructure_-based blocking**. [ref two](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/09/09/testing-mysql-partitioning-pt-online-schema-change/)

Comment: @ijoseph, I work at a company where pt-online-schema-change is used dozens of times every day, so I know it well. You're right, it copies data without locking the table the whole time. But in fact it does perform an ALTER TABLE on the new table before copying any data to that table. It does the same type of lock, it just lasts a very short amount of time.

Comment: Ah wow, glancing at your credentials I see that you also worked at Percona itself.

Comment: Ah ok, so technically `pt-online-schema-change` _does_ lock, then. However, that locking doesn't block read access because it's done on the new table before data is being read from this table, correct? Does it block write access?

Comment: Yes, it makes a copy table exactly like the original (but with no rows of data), then applies the ALTER TABLE to the new table. This is practically instant because it has no rows to restructure in the new table. The metadata lock is released after the ALTER TABLE. Then pt-osc starts copying rows from the old table to the new table in small batches. The rows fit into whatever new structure the new table has. Technically, you can write to the new table, but you'll mess it up the integrity of the copy if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Look this 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html about the alter table.

Then in particular the alter table.

ADD/DROP/COALESCE/REORGANIZE partition sql provides almost all the functions to manage your partitions.

note that hash can be only used to integer.

ALTER TABLE ... ADD PARTITION creates no temporary table except when used with NDB tables. ADD or DROP operations for RANGE or LIST partitions are immediate operations or nearly so. ADD or COALESCE operations for HASH or KEY partitions copy data between changed partitions; unless LINEAR HASH or LINEAR KEY was used, this is much the same as creating a new table (although the operation is done partition by partition). REORGANIZE operations copy only changed partitions and do not touch unchanged ones.